# Highlight a slice of pie chart in highcharts on click of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

How do I Highlight a slice of pie chart in highcharts on click of a div? More like copying the highlighting functionality of legends but from a differrent div.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2
    }]
}]
```

});

For example in the highchart above I want a different div to do what legends do here. Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-legend/

Answer (score 2):

To do this make the chart a variable and interact with it like a typical javascript Object:

```js
// Build the chart
$(function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
      },
      tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
          pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                  enabled: false
              },
              showInLegend: true
          }
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'Brands',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [{
              name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
              y: 56.33
          }, {
              name: 'Chrome',
              y: 24.03,
              sliced: true,
              selected: true
          }, {
              name: 'Firefox',
              y: 10.38
          }, {
              name: 'Safari',
              y: 4.77
          }, {
              name: 'Opera',
              y: 0.91
          }, {
              name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
              y: 0.2
          }]
      }]
  });
  
  $('#button').click(function() {
      var point = chart.series[0].data[3]; //Or any other point
      point.select();
      chart.tooltip.refresh(point);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="button" style="background-color:grey; width:100px;color:white;">Select Safari</div>
```

edit: words